# One of two images loaded in tableviewcell Larger than imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

I am downloading images from server using `SDWebImage` Library and place in `UITableViewCell` but all images Loaded in imageView correctly but last two images loaded larger than imageview size. i put imageView in A View and set aspect ratio of Parent view in which imageView is placed. i tried all content mode of imageview but not know what the problem is.but when i set aspect ratio  on imageView then that particular two last images not loaded in `UITableViewCell`.

Normal Images In `UITableViewCell`

[image]

and last two images got the imageView Bigger

[image]

but when i set aspect ratio to aspect fit on imageview in storyboard then those last two images not loaded in imageView

any suggestion

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing how you are setting the frame of the `UIImageView`.  Is it done via autolayout.  If it's the control itself that is getting larger something is wrong with setting it's frame and until that is correct the aspect ratio setting won't help.

Answer (score 0):

To have the image only show within the view that it's in (the `UIImageView`), you'll want to use this:

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

If you want it to keep it's aspect ratio within the `UIImageView`, you'll want to use this:

```
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

If this is still too large, try experimenting with:

```
.scaleAspectFit
.scaleToFill
```

Comment: In this case the `UIImageView` itself is changing frame size so neither of these will help.  Once that is resolved then these will then apply.

Comment: i added it in cellforRowAtindexPath but still the same